# Compare two columns and take their position

Tags: python

I have two files:

`file1.txt`:

```
-33.68;-53.48;Chuí;Rio Grande do Sul;Brazil;
-33.68;-53.4;Chuí;Rio Grande do Sul;Brazil;
-33.68;-53.32;Santa Vitória do Palmar;Rio Grande do Sul;Brazil;
-33.6;-53.48;Santa Vitória do Palmar;Rio Grande do Sul;Brazil;
-33.6;-53.4;Chuí;Rio Grande do Sul;Brazil;
```

`file2.txt`:

```
-37.6 -57.72 13
-37.6 -57.48 15
-33.6 -53.4 12
-33.6 -53.48 5
```

I want to compare lat and lon and join the lines

Expected result:

```
-33.6;-53.48;Santa Vitória do Palmar;Rio Grande do Sul;Brazil;5
-33.6;-53.4;Chuí;Rio Grande do Sul;Brazil;12
```

Code:

```
fileWrite  = open("out.txt","w")
gg2=[]
with open("ddprecip.txt", encoding="utf8", mode='r') as file5:
   bruto = [line.split() for line in file5]
   for dd in range(len(bruto)):
       lat = float(bruto[dd][0])
       lon = float(bruto[dd][1])
       valor= int(float(bruto[dd][2]))
       gg2.append(str(lat)+";"+str(lon)+";"+str(valor))


with open("geo2.txt", encoding="utf8", mode='r') as f:
    text = f.readlines()

for ind in range(len(bruto)):
        coord2 = (gg2[ind].split(";")[0]+";"+gg2[ind].split(";")[1])
        match = [i for i,x in enumerate(text) if coord2 in x]

        if match:
            variaveis = text[match[0]].split(";")
            show = coord2+";"+variaveis[2]+";"+variaveis[3]+";"+gg2[ind].split(";")[2]+";"+variaveis[4]
            print(show)
            fileWrite.write(str(show.encode("utf-8"))+";\n")  

fileWrite.close()
```

Problem:

If you have a lat/lon: `3.6; -53.4`
will return the line: `-33.6;-53.4;Chuí;Rio Grande do Sul;Brazil;`

I need the lat and lon to be exact in both files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making doing what you want much harder than it needs to be, in a relatively slow way that's using a lot more memory than necessary.

To speed up the whole process, a dictionary named `geo_dict` is first created from the second file. It maps each unique (lat, log) pair of value to a place name. This will make checking for matches *much* quicker than doing a linear-search through the list of all of them.

It also unnecessary to convert the values to `float`s and `int`s, in fact it might be better to *not* do it because comparing `float` values can be problematic on a computer.

Anyway, after the dictionary is created, each line in the first file can be read and processed sequentially. Note that lines with no match are skipped.

```
from pprint import pprint

with open("geo2.txt", encoding="utf8", mode='r') as file2:
    geo_dict = {tuple(line[:2]): line[2:5] for line in (line.split(';') for line in file2)}

pprint(geo_dict)
print()

with open("ddprecip.txt", encoding="utf8", mode='r') as file1, \
     open("out.txt","w") as fileWrite:
    for line in (line.split() for line in file1):
        lat, lon, valor = line[:3]
        match = geo_dict.get((lat, lon))
        if match:
            show = ';'.join(line[:2] + match[:3] + [valor])
            fileWrite.write(show + "\n")

print('Done')
```

On-screen output:

```
{('-33.6', '-53.4'): ['Chuí', 'Rio Grande do Sul', 'Brazil'],
 ('-33.6', '-53.48'): ['Santa Vitória do Palmar',
                       'Rio Grande do Sul',
                       'Brazil'],
 ('-33.68', '-53.32'): ['Santa Vitória do Palmar',
                        'Rio Grande do Sul',
                        'Brazil'],
 ('-33.68', '-53.4'): ['Chuí', 'Rio Grande do Sul', 'Brazil'],
 ('-33.68', '-53.48'): ['Chuí', 'Rio Grande do Sul', 'Brazil']}

Done
```

Contents of the `out.txt` file created:

```
-33.6;-53.4;Chuí;Rio Grande do Sul;Brazil;12
-33.6;-53.48;Santa Vitória do Palmar;Rio Grande do Sul;Brazil;5
```

Comment: thank you very much, your code is really good.
in the other code I tried to use, it took a few minutes to complete, because the files have more than 100000 lines,
with your code, runs in seconds,
Thank you

Comment: Max: Yep, but not only is it faster — the problem's gone!